# Remove Tags from Recursive Array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, strip-tags

I have below-recursive array as output

I already visited [PHP: strip the tags off the value inside array_values()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910181/php-strip-the-tags-off-the-value-inside-array-values)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <td>1</td>
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <td align="left">Normal</td>
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <td>1</td>
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <td align="left">Normal</td>
                )

        )
)
```

So for `<td>1</td>` will be `1` & `<td align="left">Normal</td>` will be `Normal`

Would like to `strip_tags` of my recursive array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try with this custom recursive strip_tags function:

```
function recursiveStripTags($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $data[$key] = recursiveStripTags($value);
        }
        else {
            $data[$key] = strip_tags($value);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

$data = recursiveStripTags($data);
```

Comment: If there is comma value `259, Tampines St.21` then it put convert it to different array. Want in same array. Don't know why it's seprating by `,`?

Comment: Can you please post the new input?

Comment: Solved that issue no worries @krasipenkow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `preg_replace()`:

```
foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
    foreach ( $arr as $ar) {
        $ar[0] = preg_replace("/<[^<]*>/", "", $ar[0]);
    }
}
```